# Choosing the best estimator

Tags: probability, statistics

Given yield measurements $X_1,X_2,X_3$ from three independent runs of an experiment with variance $\sigma^2$, which is the better of the two estimators:
$\hat\theta_{1}$= $\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3}{3}$,                  $\hat\theta_{2}$=$\frac{X_1+2X_2+X_3}{4}$

I know that in order to find the best estimator if both are unbiased, we are supposed to choose the one with the smallest variance.  I need help just starting this problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Variance of the Sample mean estimate is just $$\text{VAR}(\bar{\mu})=\text{VAR}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i}{n}\right)$$ for the first case and $$\text{VAR}(\bar{\mu_2})=\text{VAR}\left(\frac{X_1+X_2+X_2+X_3}{4}\right)$$ in the second. Now apply scaling property of variances to see which one has a higher variance.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $\text{Var}(X_1+X_2) = \text{Var}(X_1)+\text{Var}(X_2)$ if they are independent
- $\text{Var}(k X) = k^2 \text{Var}(X)$  and so $\text{Var}\left(\dfrac{X}{k}\right) = \dfrac{\text{Var}(X)}{k^2} $

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear without computing that sample mean is the best estimator for the problem; computing variances gives

$$\mathbb{Var}(\hat{\theta}_1)=\frac{\sigma^2+\sigma^2+\sigma^2}{3^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{3}$$
$$\mathbb{Var}(\hat{\theta}_2)=\frac{\sigma^2+2^2\sigma^2+\sigma^2}{4^2}=\frac{3\sigma^2}{8}$$